# Trigger function inside the same function

Tags: jquery, triggers

Came across a Function which had a trigger that references to the same function. What happens in such situation. Does the `start()` keep calling itself? or it happens only once?

```
function start() {
    $(window).trigger('start');
    update();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `trigger` method is for firing events ("Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type."). Therefore, this code is firing a custom event named `start`, not calling the function `start`. Any event listeners bound to `window` would receive this event when `start()` is called.

See the [jQuery docs for trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) for more information.

Comment: so if i  have $(window).on('start end', function);
does it get fired on start as well as end? (or should they be separated via a comma)

Comment: The documentation states "One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces," so you are correct to separate them with a space, yes (http://api.jquery.com/on/).